# How do I get GraphQL query to get data for a specific Pancake LP pair from pancake swap hosted graph

Tags: the-graph, subgraph

I am trying to get Pancake-Pair data by quering the subgraph (Hosted at : `https://thegraph.com/hosted-service/subgraph/mmontes11/pancakeswap`) .

I want to filter data by pair-contract address . I thought of writing it in the where clause .

Something like this  :

```
pairHourDatas(
    first: 24
    where: { pair: "Pancake_lp_address" }
    orderBy: hourStartUnix
    orderDirection: desc
  ) {
    id
    hourStartUnix
    reserve0
    reserve1
    reserveUSD
    pair {
      token0 {
        id
      }
      token1 {
        id
      }
    }
  }
```

But the query is incorrect .  Is this the correct query format . If not how can I query this specific endpoint .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct, just note that addresses in The Graph are all lowercase.

For example, for the pair `0x0002D9a4Af937b6c85497a77906b44f6ADfC8702` you cannot use the checksummed address; instead, you must use `0x0002d9a4af937b6c85497a77906b44f6adfc8702`.

This works on the graph you linked:

```
{
  pairHourDatas(
    first: 24
    where: { pair: "0x0002d9a4af937b6c85497a77906b44f6adfc8702" }
    orderBy: hourStartUnix
    orderDirection: desc
  ) {
    id
    hourStartUnix
    reserve0
    reserve1
    reserveUSD
    pair {
      token0 {
        id
      }
      token1 {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```